# Exibir mensagem de erro corretamente

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu tenho esse código:

```
flash[:error] = t("errors.messages.restrict_dependent_destroy.many")
```

e o sistema mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem **%{record}** dependentes

Eu quero que mostre dessa forma:

> Não é possível excluir o registro pois existem **categorias** dependentes

Como devo fazer?

Comment: Tu tentou editar o arquivo `locales/*.yml`?

Comment: Cara, eu até poderia, mas preciso utilizar a mesma key para os outros models como equipamentos e etc.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve passar parâmetros para [interpolação](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation).

```
    t("errors.messages.restrict_dependent_destroy.many", record: "categorias")
```

E para deixar genérico você pode obter o nome através do objeto:

```
    t("errors.messages.restrict_dependent_destroy.many", record: objeto_dependente.class.model_name.plural)
```

Mas, se você está utilizando a validação `dependent: :restrict_with_error` nas associações dos models, o Rails já gera a mensagem de erro para você. Para acessá-la utilize:

```
    flash[:error] = objeto_pai.errors[:base].join("\n")
```